# Print table without HTML tags for use in calculations

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, python-3.4

I'm trying to get the names of the participants and odds from this website into a list or table that I can then do calculations with. I would like to view the data in an ordered output like this below

```
1.name / odds vs name / odds
2.name / odds vs name / odds
```

Currently I can only seem to grab them separately and when I print them they still contain the HTML tags.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('http://www.oddschecker.com/tennis/match-coupon')
html = url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

odds = soup.find_all("span", "odds")
print(odds)
```

I would love to be able to run calculations on the data once I can structure it in the above format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to iterate over table rows (`tr` tags with `data-market-id` attribute present), find all participants and odds [by class names](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class). And you need to get element's texts via [`get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

Working example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('http://www.oddschecker.com/tennis/match-coupon')
html = url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for row in soup.find_all("tr", {"data-market-id": True}):
    participants = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in row.find_all('span', class_='fixtures-bet-name')]
    odds = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in row.find_all('span', class_='odds')]

    print participants[0], odds[0], participants[1], odds[1]
```

Prints:

```
Tomas Berdych (9/4) Roger Federer (5/12)
Milos Raonic (15/8) Rafael Nadal (8/15)
...
Vera Lapko (5/6) Julia Terziyska (5/6)
Aminat Kushkhova (11/10) Katie Swan (4/6)
```

Comment: Am i right in thinking that participants and odds are both strings, and that i need to convert the odds into a float in order to do a calculation with them?

Comment: where in the current script should i try and convert the string to a float? i've tried applying here

'odds = [float(item.get_text)(strip=True) for item in row.find_all('span', class_='odds')]'

Comment: @TwiggyGarcia try `odds = [float(item.get_text(strip=True)) for item in row.find_all('span', class_='odds')]`

Comment: still picking up an error 'ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(8/15)'